# it.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com replaces it.archive.ubuntu.com?

Tags: apt, updates

For a few days now, I have had this error in all my Ubuntu Server VPSs:

```
# apt update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Err:2 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                               
  Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:70). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:73). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:72). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (90.147.160.72), connection timed out Could not connect to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (90.147.160.73), connection timed out Could not connect to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (90.147.160.70), connection timed out
Err:3 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease    
  Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:70). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:73). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:72). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:4 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease  
  Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:70). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:73). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:72). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
```

I solved with:

```
sed -i 's/http:\/\/it./http:\/\/it.clouds./g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Does somebody know why `it.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com` replaces `it.archive.ubuntu.com`?
Is the same for other country codes different from `it`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where initially `it.archive.ubuntu.com` came from.

The suggested Italian repository mirrors are:

```
giano.com.dist.unige.it
ubuntu.conessi.it
ubuntu.mirror.garr.it
```

You can use any mirror you like from any country.

Comment: Thank you for your response. `it.archive.ubuntu.com` is the default I found automatically set. That's why I'm surprised it was changed to `it.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com`, breaking the apt functionality.